# Why free form does not shows exact code?

Tags: free-form-input

*Edit: more example added*

I am reading "Hands-On Start to Wolfram Mathematica: And Programming with the Wolfram Language 2nd. Edition".

From the page 27:

If I run in free input:

```
population of the United States
```

I am getting:
[image]

but in the book it is like:

[image]

**Question:** Why I am not getting `CountryData["UnitedStates", "Population"]` like in book?

---

Also, at page 12 there is an example to in put in free form (`=` and after text):

```
life expectancy in the US
```

After book says that I should look at expanded results (by pressing `+`) and I should get a command for more precise way of evaluation:

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", "LifeExpectancy"]
```

But when I press `+` I do not see such code. Again not getting Mathematica code.

Comment: Are you pressing the `+` icon in the panel of the output rather than on the keyboard?

Comment: @BobHanlon I am pressing `+` in the **input** right side after evaluation. I do not see any `+` in the output.

Comment: @BobHanlon Other example with screenshot added.

Comment: At some point Mathematica switched to the entity icon display format. The graphical icons can be converted to `InputForm`, e.g., `Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"][
  EntityProperty["Country", 
   "Population"]]` and `Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"][
  EntityProperty["Country", 
   "LifeExpectancy"]]`. The book shows an older, shorter form that still works and produces the same outputs. This is not related to the plus icon. Pressing the plus icon produces an additional panel with much more information.

Comment: @BobHanlon How to convert that to input form programatically. I tried in free-form `InputForm[population of the United States]` without success.

Comment: I don't know about programmatically; click on one of the icons and the panel goes away. Select the cell and use the menu command `Cell | Convert To | InputForm` or the keyboard shortcut `Command + Shift + I`

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? `Interpreter["SemanticExpression"]["population of the united states"]`?

Comment: @BobHanlon That solves the problem. Thank you.