# How to display the code generated from Free Form Input(=)?

Tags: free-form-input

It seems like not all results output from Free Form Input provide the exact code that was used. For example here you can see that only code for "density of air" was output:
[image]

In the other cases only the result was given.

A similar question was asked here:[Why free form does not shows exact code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215205/why-free-form-does-not-shows-exact-code)
However none of the suggestions given in the comments section work.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The suggestion "convert to `InputForm` with Ctrl+Shift+I" works for 3rd case.